# How to access native Android sensor signal processing algorithms?

Tags: android, algorithm, signal-processing, android-sensors

I'm looking for where to find native Android algorithms' codes used to process signals comming from the sensors.

I want to know exactly which algorithms are used in processing sensor signals and how signals of software sensors are generated such as gravity and linear acceleration.

Answer (score 0):

The way Google calculates Linear Acceleration is not part of the AOSP. That information is proprietary of Google and not available